# How do I split in two columns an ordered list with sub ordered list and keep counter?

Tags: html, css, html-lists, dompdf

I'm building a pdf template with dompdf (laravel) that requires an ol with some ol inside and in two columns, I've tryed some answers about two columns ol and about make sub ol but when I put them together is all chaos. My code is like this:

```
<ol>
  <li>item 1</li> //column 1
  <li>item 2</li> //column 1
  <li>item 3      //column 1
    <ol>          //column 2 needs to start in 3.1
      <li>item 3.1</li> //column 2
      <li>item 3.2</li> //column 2
    </ol>
  </li>
  </ol>
```

i've tryed a lot, here my code:

```css
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}


/* Clear floats after the columns */

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

ol.normal {
  counter-reset: item;
}

ol.normal>li {
  display: block
}

ol.normal>li:before,
ol.reset>li:before {
  content: counters(item, ".") " ";
  counter-increment: item
}
```

```html
<div class="row fs-small">
  <div class="column">
    <ol class="normal fs-small" type="1">
      <li value="1">
        <span class="fs-small bold">xxx</span>
        <ol class="normal" type="1">
          <li>
            <span>xxx</span>
          </li>
          <li>
            <span>xxx</span>
          </li>
        </ol>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="fs-small bold">xxx</span>
        <ol class="normal">
          <li>
            <span>xxx</span>
          </li>
        </ol>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="fs-small bold">xxxx</span>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <ol class="normal">
      <li>
        <ol class="normal">
          <li>
            <span>xxx</span>
          </li>
          <li>
            <span>xxx<span>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <span>xxx</span>
          </li>
          <li>
            <span>
                            xxx
                        </span>
          </li>
          <li>
            <span>
                            xxx
                        </span>
          </li>
          <li>
            <span>xxx
                        </span>
          </li>
        </ol>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what this is supposed to look like. Can you clarify?

Comment: well I solve it manually setting the number in the ol and sub-number in the li with an attribute and using that in the css.

Answer (score 0):

you may use flex and split your list from 2 ol list . counter-css is handy and can be simplified without use of a class, only from the tree level:

possible example

```css
div {
  counter-reset: olfirst olbis;
  display: flex;
}

div>ol {
  flex: 1;
}

div ol li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

div>ol>li:before {
  counter-increment: olfirst;
}

li:before {
  content: counter(olfirst);
  float: left;
  color: tomato;
}

ol li ol li:first-of-type {
  counter-reset: olbis;
}

li li:before {
  counter-increment: olbis;
  content: counter(olfirst)'.' counter(olbis) ' ';
  padding-right: 1em;
  color: green
}

ol ol {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  padding-left: 1em;
```

```html
<div>
  <ol>
    <li>
      <ol>
        <li>XXX</li>
        <li>XXX</li>
        <li>XXX</li>
        <li>XXX</li>
      </ol>
    </li>
    <li>
      <ol>
        <li>XXX</li>
        <li>XXX</li>
      </ol>
    </li>
    <li>
      <ol>
        <li>XXX</li>
        <li>XXX</li>
        <li>XXX</li>
      </ol>
    </li>
  </ol>
  <ol>
    <li>
      <ol>
        <li>XXX</li>
        <li>XXX</li>
        <li>XXX</li>
      </ol>
    </li>
  </ol>
```

---

from comment : update with other display options

- table/table-cell

```css
div {
  counter-reset: olfirst olbis;
  display: table;
  width:100%;
}

div>ol {
  display: table-cell;
}

div ol li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

div>ol>li:before {
  counter-increment: olfirst;
}

li:before {
  content: counter(olfirst);
  float: left;
  color: tomato;
}

ol li ol li:first-of-type {
  counter-reset: olbis;
}

li li:before {
  counter-increment: olbis;
  content: counter(olfirst)'.' counter(olbis) ' ';
  padding-right: 1em;
  color: green
}

ol ol {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  padding-left: 1em;
```

```html
<div>
  <ol>
    <li>
      <ol>
        <li>XXX</li>
        <li>XXX</li>
        <li>XXX</li>
        <li>XXX</li>
      </ol>
    </li>
    <li>
      <ol>
        <li>XXX</li>
        <li>XXX</li>
      </ol>
    </li>
    <li>
      <ol>
        <li>XXX</li>
        <li>XXX</li>
        <li>XXX</li>
      </ol>
    </li>
  </ol>
  <ol>
    <li>
      <ol>
        <li>XXX</li>
        <li>XXX</li>
        <li>XXX</li>
      </ol>
    </li>
  </ol>
```

- inline-block

```css
div {
  counter-reset: olfirst olbis;
}

div>ol {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
}

div ol li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

div>ol>li:before {
  counter-increment: olfirst;
}

li:before {
  content: counter(olfirst);
  float: left;
  color: tomato;
}

ol li ol li:first-of-type {
  counter-reset: olbis;
}

li li:before {
  counter-increment: olbis;
  content: counter(olfirst)'.' counter(olbis) ' ';
  padding-right: 1em;
  color: green
}

ol ol {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  padding-left: 1em;
```

```html
<div>
  <ol>
    <li>
      <ol>
        <li>XXX</li>
        <li>XXX</li>
        <li>XXX</li>
        <li>XXX</li>
      </ol>
    </li>
    <li>
      <ol>
        <li>XXX</li>
        <li>XXX</li>
      </ol>
    </li>
    <li>
      <ol>
        <li>XXX</li>
        <li>XXX</li>
        <li>XXX</li>
      </ol>
    </li>
  </ol>
  <ol>
    <li>
      <ol>
        <li>XXX</li>
        <li>XXX</li>
        <li>XXX</li>
      </ol>
    </li>
  </ol>
```

float will do too.

```css
div {
  counter-reset: olfirst olbis;
}

div>ol {
  float:left;
}

div ol li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

div>ol>li:before {
  counter-increment: olfirst;
}

li:before {
  content: counter(olfirst);
  float: left;
  color: tomato;
}

ol li ol li:first-of-type {
  counter-reset: olbis;
}

li li:before {
  counter-increment: olbis;
  content: counter(olfirst)'.' counter(olbis) ' ';
  padding-right: 1em;
  color: green
}

ol ol {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  padding-left: 1em;
```

```html
<div>
  <ol>
    <li>
      <ol>
        <li>XXX</li>
        <li>XXX</li>
        <li>XXX</li>
        <li>XXX</li>
      </ol>
    </li>
    <li>
      <ol>
        <li>XXX</li>
        <li>XXX</li>
      </ol>
    </li>
    <li>
      <ol>
        <li>XXX</li>
        <li>XXX</li>
        <li>XXX</li>
      </ol>
    </li>
  </ol>
  <ol>
    <li>
      <ol>
        <li>XXX</li>
        <li>XXX</li>
        <li>XXX</li>
      </ol>
    </li>
  </ol>
```

Comment: @Vla added a few other classic ways ;)

Answer (score -1):

Okay here you can try To split in two columns an ordered list with sub ordered list and keep counter use start style.